# Multiple Criteria with IF, AND and OR Statement

Tags: excel

This is the criteria I am trying to write for:

If any score for test 1 in the past five years (columns E-I) is above x (Contained in Cell Z2) 
and 
If any score for test 2 in the past five years (columns K-O) is above y (Contained in Cell Y2)
or 
visa versa (Test 1 above y (in cell Y2) and Test 2 above x (in cell Z2) 
then return "yes"
otherwise "no".

This is what I have tried and so far failed at:

=IF((COUNTIF(E3:I3,">="&$Y$2)+COUNTIF(K3:O3,">="&$Z$2))OR IF((COUNTIF(E3:I3,">="&$Z$2)+COUNTIF(K3:O3,">="&$Y$2),"Y","N")))

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{=IF(OR(E3:I3>=$Y$2,K3:O3>=$Z$2),"yes","no")}
```

Please note, that you don't have to write the `{}` brackets, this means, that this is an array formula, which means you need to enter the forrmula and instead of pressing enter, you need to press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to submit the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Your IF and OR form an incorrect syntax. The correct syntax is

```
IF(OR(ConditionA,ConditionB),ResultIfTrue,ResultIfFalse)
```